# Does SyncTeX work with Emacs polymode?

Tags: polymode

Specifically, I want to sync an Rnoweb (Rnw) source with a PDF opened in either Skim or Evince using polymode. Note that I have no problem weaving or exporting Rnw files and viewing PDFs with Skim. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. SyncTex links the (La)TeX source with the PDF output. Compiling an Rnw file to PDF requires an intermediate .tex file, and I don't think SyncTex can manage the links between Rnw <-> Tex <-> PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tyler. Currently there are a few editors that support SynTeX between Rnw and PDF. To name a few, [RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552066-PDF-Preview-and-SyncTeX), [TeXShop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901174/synchronise-pdf-to-rnw-in-knitr-with-texshop/34620136#34620136), and [TeXmaker](http://www.r-bloggers.com/use-sweave-with-texmaker-and-make-synctex-work-properly-with-it/). I am wondering if there is a similar way to set up SynTeX for polymode.

Comment: So it's not impossible! I don't know if it's available yet for Emacs, hopefully someone else will know.